# Jar file will not launch

Tags: java, jar

I have used eclipse's export option to package my program as an executable jar, but I cannot get the file to run by double clicking. It has a main class and I have checked countless times that I packaged it correctly. What else do I need to do to make it run on a double click?

Answer (score 0):

Is your project a commandline application? if it is: the console doesn't automatically show up when you start a jar. you'll have to launch it via the console